# Simulink Slip Rate Control (ABS Modelling)

Tags: simulink

I am trying to limit one input (Tb, which is a step input) while comparing some other variable (s, calculated in the model) to a set of conditions: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4y2ni6dd1bf6ui9/11.jpg

The picture shows the variation of Tb as required for a give s curve

How do i implement this logic in a simulink model. I need to add this logic to an existing model.

Comment: Your question is worded in a somewhat confusing way (at least it was confusing to me). Based on your drawing, are you saying that Tb is a function of s. When s>0.95 then Tb=0. When s<0.25 then Tb = the opposite of its previous value (i.e. Tb=1 if previously Tb=0 and vice-versa). When 0.25<=s<=0.95 then Tb = previous value of Tb.  Is that what you're aiming for?